# Декоратор, изменяющий количество возвращаемых параметров - нарушает "дух" Python?

Tags: python, декоратор, cleancode

При работе с API в примерно таком классе:

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Tuple, Any  # , TypeVar, Iterable

import requests
import json


class API_working:
    def __init__(self, some_cridentials: dict):
        self.url = some_cridentials['url']
        ...


    def api_method_x(self, params: dict):
        send_json = 'somesing json here from *params'
        response = requests.post(
            url="/".join([self.url, 'citySearch']),
            headers=self.content_type,
            json=send_json,
        )

        self.auth_response_code = response.status_code
        content_result = json.loads(response.content)['result']
        return response.status_code, content_result

...
```

есть много методов  типа `api_method_x`, заканчивающихся на один и тот же набор операторов:

```
        self.auth_response_code = response.status_code
        content_result = json.loads(response.content)['result']
        return response.status_code, content_result
```

Я могу вынести их в декоратор:

```
def return_unpacked_response(self,
                         method: Callable[[Any, dict], dict]
                         ) -> Callable[[Any, dict], Tuple[str, dict]]:
    def wrapper(self):
        response = method(self, dict)

        self.auth_response_code = response.status_code
        content_result = json.loads(response.content)['result']
        return response.status_code, content_result

return wrapper
```

И тогда методы такого типа будут выглядеть так:

```
class API_working:
    def __init__(self, some_cridentials: dict):
        self.url = some_cridentials['url']
        ...


@return_unpacked_response
def api_method_x(self, params: dict):
    send_json = 'somesing json here from *params'
    response = requests.post(
        url="/".join([self.url, 'citySearch']),
        headers=self.content_type,
        json=send_json,
    )
    return response
...
```

Но у меня есть сомнения по поводу общепринятости такой практики в смысле чистоты кода.  Получается, что декоратор - распаковуя `response`, возвращает 2 параметра вместо 1 -го, как было в декорируемой функции. Это может быть неочевидным другому программисту при чтении.
Вопрос: Как лучше с точки зрения `python-style` кода?

Может, лучше, воспользоваться принципом `DRY` и просто сделать еще один метод:

```
class API_working:
def __init__(self, some_cridentials: dict):
    self.url = some_cridentials['url']
    ...


def __unpack_response(self, response: Any) -> Tuple[str, dict]:
        self.auth_response_code = response.status_code
        content_result = json.loads(response.content)['result']
        return response.status_code, content_result


def api_method_x(self, params: dict):
    send_json = 'somesing json here from *params'
    response = requests.post(
        url="/".join([self.url, 'citySearch']),
        headers=self.content_type,
        json=send_json,
    )

    return self.__unpack_response(response)

...
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я выбрал второй вариант, если что.
Без неочевидного изменения количества возвращаемых данных. То есть:

```
class API_working:
def __init__(self, some_cridentials: dict):
    self.url = some_cridentials['url']
    ...


def __unpack_response(self, response: Any) -> Tuple[str, dict]:
        self.auth_response_code = response.status_code
        content_result = json.loads(response.content)['result']
        return response.status_code, content_result


def api_method_x(self, params: dict):
    send_json = 'somesing json here from *params'
    response = requests.post(
        url="/".join([self.url, 'citySearch']),
        headers=self.content_type,
        json=send_json,
    )

    return self.__unpack_response(response)

...
```